# Cloudfoundry (Bosh-lite) app push is timeout

Tags: cloud-foundry

I trying CF on day 1. Deployed local cloud foundry on Mac with Bosh lite. No issues in doing so. Also added mysql build pack without any issue. But when i try to push the app it is taking forever and fails. After few tries it succeeded once, but the app is failing to start with time out. So to increate timeout i did re-push the app with command;

cf push pong_matcher_spring -t 180 -p /DEV/github/cloudfoundry-samples/pong_matcher_spring/target/pong-matcher-spring-1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar -m 256M -i 1 -n app1

The app never getting pushed. Pleas see below log;

————————————————————————————————————————————

cf push pong_matcher_spring -t 180 -p /DEV/github/cloudfoundry-samples/pong_matcher_spring/target/pong-matcher-spring-1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar -m 256M -i 1 -n app1
Using manifest file /DEV/github/cloudfoundry-samples/pong_matcher_spring/manifest.yml

Creating app pong_matcher_spring in org scientia / space development as admin...
OK

Creating route app1.bosh-lite.com...
OK

Binding app1.bosh-lite.com to pong_matcher_spring...
OK

Uploading pong_matcher_spring...
Uploading app files from: /DEV/github/cloudfoundry-samples/pong_matcher_spring/target/pong-matcher-spring-1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
Uploading 798.3K, 116 files
Done uploading
OK
Binding service mysql to app pong_matcher_spring in org scientia / space development as admin...
OK

Starting app pong_matcher_spring in org scientia / space development as admin...
-----> Downloaded app package (23M)

FAILED
StagingError

TIP: use 'cf logs pong_matcher_spring --recent' for more information
————————————————————————————————————————————

I could not find anything in job logs apart from these messages.

I suspect there is something with the network. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: A simple restart and the Vagrant VM solved the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Restart the Vagrant VM solved the issue.